# What is the difference between ObservableCollection and INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am confused about how `ObservableCollection` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` works.

I have this code:

```
Payments = new ObservableCollection<PaymentViewModel>(_allPayments);

public ObservableCollection<PaymentViewModel> Payments
{
    get { return _payments; }
    set {
        _payments = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Payments");
    }
}
```

I don't understand what is the relationship between `ObservableCollection` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` here. Can you explain?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ObservableCollection` is a specialized collection that can notify subscribers when its *contents* change, while `INotifyPropertyChanged` is an interface that allows implementors to notify subscribers when one of their *properties* changes value.

You are probably wondering how the two are related (because both are "involved" in the setter in your example).

Consider this code:

```
var model = new MyViewModel(); // assume it's the class with Payments inside
model.Payments.Add(new PaymentViewModel());
```

Subscribers to the [`INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.collectionchanged.aspx) event would now know that things have changed and they should update accordingly.

But now look at this:

```
var model = new MyViewModel(); // assume it's the class with Payments inside
model.Payments.Add(new PaymentViewModel()); // OK, we know what this does

model.Payments = new ObservableCollection<PaymentViewModel>();
```

After adding an item to the collection we then *swap the entire collection for another one*. If an `ItemsControl` is bound to this collection we expect it to update itself and reflect the fact that `model.Payments` ends up being empty. But how can it do that?

`CollectionChanged` will not help because the original collection (after receiving its first item) was not modified; we just discarded it and installed another in its place. The only one who knows that the switch happened is the `Payments` property setter. So the setter utilizes `INotifyPropertyChanged` to tell subscribers that the collection has been replaced with another, and they should of course update their status.

**Conclusion:** Data binding works automagically in WPF because all the databound controls listen to the `INotifyPropertyChanged` of their `DataContext`, *and* if the binding target implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` they subscribe to that as well. If the binding target changes they are notified through `INotifyPropertyChanged`, unsubscribe from `INotifyCollectionChanged` on the old target and subscribe to it on the new one.

Answer (score 2):

An ObservableCollection notifies its binder, with for example when something is added/deleted to the collection itself.

What you're doing in the second example however, is notifying the binder that the collection has been replaced by a new collection (something that the ObservableCollection does not do itself, if you do new ObservableCollection - there you lose the binding).

Comment: i also understand your answer .you also give good answer.thank you.