# Observablecollection not updating list, when an item gets added

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I'm using the MVVM pattern and want to update a ListView using an observable collection. I went through several SO questions, but cannot see what I'm doing wrong. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

**View.xaml**

Namespace: `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MusicPlayer.ViewModel"`

DataContext

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:AllTracksViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

ListView

```
<ListView x:Name="TrackListView" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TrackListObservable}">
...
<ListView.View>
   <GridView>
     <GridViewColumn Header="Title" Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}" />
      <GridViewColumn Header="Album" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Album}" />
      <GridViewColumn Header="Artist" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Artist}" />
      <GridViewColumn Header="Duration" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FormattedDuration}" />
      </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class AllTracksViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Track> TrackListObservable { get; private set; }

    public AllTracksViewModel()
    {
        TrackListObservable = new ObservableCollection<Track>();
    }
}
```

I verified that items are definitely getting added to the observable.
Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you implementing INotifyPropertyChanged correctly?

Comment: Post the code where you update the observablecollection.

Comment: @sthotakura I don't have any code. I though the collection does that automatically...

Comment: I meant the code where you add items to the observable collection.

Comment: You dont need INotifyPropertyChanged. you just have to bind to list correctly. see my answer below

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary the ListView is in a UserControl (I probably should have mentioned that). I thought that there shouldn't be any code behind the view class?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary You are incorrect. The way the code currently is, a new ObservableCollection is created and assigned to `TrackListObservable`, so INPC is required and `TrackListObservable` needs to notify. Currently it is an autogenerated property so no notification takes place when the collection is replaced.

Comment: @slugster ahh. Thank you. I will try it out :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
public class AllTracksViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ObservableCollection<Track> trackListObservable;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<Track> TrackListObservable {
      get { return trackListObservable; }
      set {
        trackListObservable = value;
        if(PropertyChanged!=null) {
          PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TrackListObservable"));
        }
      }
}

    public AllTracksViewModel()
    {
        TrackListObservable = new ObservableCollection<Track>();
    }
}
```

Just to explain why: every property of your ViewModel should notify of its changes.

Comment: Doesn't ObservableCollection already implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Yes it does, but your TrackListObservable doesn't so it doesn't notify when it is changed.

Comment: @HaloMediaz Not quite - ObservableCOllection implements INotifyCollectionChanged so that when items are added/removed then anything bound gets updated. You still need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and have individual properties notify that they've updated otherwise the binding subsystem will never know that the observable collection was assigned to the property.

Comment: @slugster I don't need to know when individual items are updated. I only need to know when an item was added/removed and that item then reflect the changes in the listview.

Comment: ObservableCollection already does this. But I thing you missed INotifyPropertyChanged. Did you try my solution?

Comment: `ObservableCollection<T>` does not have implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Model classes should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Please, read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246859/what-is-the-difference-between-observablecollection-and-inotifypropertychanged

Comment: I'm glad for you HaloMediaz. As I mentioned and StepUp mentioned, a good takeaway is always to notify of property changes in your ViewModel. Don't ever thing about it: notify in every set. :-)

Comment: @slugster afters hours of searching "You still need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and have individual properties notify that they've updated otherwise..." was the key phrase. I'm using the Prism library, but once I realized the individual properties also needed to be setup for notification, it all worked. Thanks!

Comment: @dvdhns Thanks for your feedback. If you're still fighting with notification, and generally speaking with MVVM I recomment reading my Learn WPF MVVM book: https://www.amazon.com/dp/1326847996

Answer (score 1):

You should write this as itemsource

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel.TrackListObservable}"
```

And also set data context of windows to it self.

```
<Window DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" ...
```

With this property in MainWindow.

```
public AllTracksViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new AllTracksViewModel();
```

Note that you have to add items to this property. `ViewModel.TrackListObservable`

You should also remove

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:AllTracksViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

since the data context is the main window it self, thats why itemsource is set to `ViewModel.TrackListObservable`

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correctly. However, I cannot see the method which populates your `TrackListObservable`. I suggest to you to call a populating method `FillData` inside of a constructor. Let me show an example:

```
public class AllTracksViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Track> _trackListObservable;
    public ObservableCollection<Track> TrackListObservable
    {
       get { return _trackListObservable; }
       set { 
             _trackListObservable = value;                 
           }
    }

    public AllTracksViewModel()
    {
         FillData();
    }

    private void FillData()
    {
       _trackListObservable = new ObservableCollection<Track>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
           TrackListObservable.Add(new Track() { Title = "Ben & Joseph " + i.ToString(), 
                                                                 Artist = "Albahari" });
        }   
    }
}
```

Please, see a work example of [binding ListView using MVVM pattern.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34989744/how-can-i-bind-a-container-to-listview-control-in-mvvm-standard-with-caliburn-mi/34990235#34990235)

Comment: @HaloMediaz feel free to ask any question.

Answer (score 0):

Here your Property **TrackListObservable** must be a INotify Property or Dependency Property.So that only you can achieve the result what you want.

Refer the below link regards INotify Property:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms743695(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Please consider not just repeating the solution without adding anything.