# Adding an Item to ObservableCollection is not updating CollectionView in .NET MAUI app

Tags: maui, observablecollection, community-toolkit-mvvm

I found quite a few questions/answers about this here on SO but I'm confused about something. Here's one example: [Observablecollection not updating list, when an item gets added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35975364/observablecollection-not-updating-list-when-an-item-gets-added)

Shouldn't adding a new item to an `ObservableCollection<T>` automatically trigger a UI update? A lot of people are suggesting solutions that indicate developer should manually call `NotifyPropertyChanged()` but if that's the case, why use an `ObservableCollection` in the first place? Again, I'm specifically talking about adding a new item to the `ObservableCollection` and NOT updating a property of an existing item.

Using the following code, I add a brand new item to my `ObservableCollection<Student>` and there's no change in the UI even though the new item is added to the `ObservableCollection`.

Here's my view model code:

```cs
public partial Class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    //...
    public ObservableCollection<Student> Students { get; } = new();
    
    [RelayCommand]
    void AddStudent(Student student)
    {
        Students.Add(student);
    }
}
```

And my `CollectionView` binds to `Students` like so:

```xml
<CollectionView
    ItemsSource={Binding Students}>
    <!-- Omitted for brevity -->
</CollectionView>
```

Comment: Depends on when Students is initialized and the viewmodel applied as binding context for this view. Your property should include a setter and an OnPropertyChanged call in order for the view to be notified of someone setting a new collection to this property

Comment: Essentially, you're right, it should work with an `ObservableCollection<T>` as you described. How are you setting the `BindingContext`? Where does the `student` argument come from in your command? Can you step into the method? What happens then?

Comment: @Julian I set the `BindingContext` to my view model in the `ContentPage` constructor as well as in XAML i.e. `x:DataType="vm:MyViewModel"`. For brevity I didn't include all the code but there's a search box at the top and as user types student names, I suggest students and when user selects one, I call the `AddStudent` command. When I step through the code, everything is working as expected except the UI isn't updating but I confirm that the student is added to `Students` collection by putting break points before and after the `Students.Add(student);`.

Comment: It would be helpful to see some more relevant code, but setting the `BindingContext` in the constructor of your page sounds right. *Note: Setting the `x:DataType` is not equivalent to setting the `BindingContext`. The `x:DataType` serves two purposes: 1. Allowing the designer to evaluate bindings in the IDE, 2. enable compiled bindings to evaluate binding expressions during compile time and boost binding performance during runtime.*

Comment: If you don't use the MVVM Toolkit does it work then? Would be weird, but just trying to narrow down causes. This should just work. Also are you in .NET 7? 8? Does this happen only on a single platform or all? I guess a small project showing this issue would be helpful

Comment: Just to consider all the options, could it be possible that the UI is being updated, but the `CollectionView` doesn't have an `Height`, so it seems that nothing is happening? I have this doubt because at the beginning the `ObservableCollection` is empty. Could you try initializing it with one or two students? Or setting manually the `Height` property of `CollectionView`? Or even ensure that the `CollectionView` is inside an expanded layout, like a `Grid`?

Comment: @RiccardoMinato Thank you! This feels like a good time to eat some humble pie and publicly admit the stupid mistake I was making. You were partially right. It wasn't the height of the `CollectionView` but the `IsVisible` setting! Thank you all for chiming in with your input. I appreciate it!